# I want to update the displayed list to the latest state when returning from the transition destination with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

ListView displays a list of items added to favorites.

Go to DetailView and remove the item from your favorites.

And when I return to the list view, I want to update it to the latest list.

How do you do it?

### Code

#### ListView.swift

A list of 3x3 card types is displayed.

```
struct ListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fetcher = DataFetcher()
    private let columns: Int = 3

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView() {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(0..<self.fetcher.dataCount/self.columns) { rowIndex in
                            HStack {
                                ForEach(0..<self.columns) { columnIndex in
                                    self.getCell(
                                        item: self.getItem(rowIndex: rowIndex, columnIndex: columnIndex),
                                        width: self.cellWidth(width: geometry.size.width),
                                        height: self.cellHeight(width: geometry.size.width))
                                }
                            }
                        }

                      if (self.fetcher.dataCount % self.columns > 0) {
                          HStack {
                              ForEach(0..<self.fetcher.dataCount % self.columns) { lastColumnIndex in
                                  self.getCell(
                                      item: self.getItem(lastColumnIndex: lastColumnIndex),
                                      width: self.cellWidth(width: geometry.size.width),
                                      height: self.cellHeight(width: geometry.size.width))
                              }
                              Spacer()
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("list")
            }
        }
    }

    private func cellWidth(width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return (width  - 60) / CGFloat(columns)
    }

    private func cellHeight(width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return cellWidth(width: (width)) * 1.414
    }

    private func getItem(rowIndex: Int, columnIndex: Int) -> TrackModel {
        return fetcher.data[columns * rowIndex + columnIndex]
    }

    private func getItem(lastColumnIndex: Int) -> TrackModel {
        return self.fetcher.data[self.columns * (self.fetcher.dataCount / self.columns) + lastColumnIndex]
    }

    private func getCell(item: ItemModel, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> AnyView {
        return AnyView(
            NavigationLink(
                destination: etailView(itemModel: item)
            ) {
                ItemRow(itemModel: item)
                .frame(width: width, height: height)
            }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        )
    }
}
```

#### DataFetcher.swift

Firestore has a collection of "users" and "items".

Each user's document has a collection of "items".

"items" has a reference type "item" and the value is "items / documentID".

```
class DataFetcher: ObservableObject {
    typealias PublisherType = PassthroughSubject
    @Published var data: [TrackModel] = []
    @Published var dataCount: Int = 0
    private let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    private let uid: String
    private var db: Firestore!
    private let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    private let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue")

    init() {
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        uid = self.userDefaults.object(forKey: "userDataUid") as! String
        fetchData()
    }

    private func fetchData() {
        self.db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("items").getDocuments { (snaps, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            }

            guard let snaps = snaps else { return }

            for document in snaps.documents {
                self.dispatchGroup.enter()
                self.dispatchQueue.async(group: self.dispatchGroup) { [weak self] in
                    self?.asyncProcess(document: document) { (snap2: DocumentSnapshot) -> Void in
                        self!.data.append(TrackModel(
                            documentId: snap2.documentID,
                            title: snap2.data()!["title"] as! String,
                            image: snap2.data()!["image"] as! String
                        ))
                        self?.dispatchGroup.leave()
                    }
                }
            }

            self.dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                self.dataCount = self.data.count
            }
        }
    }

    func asyncProcess(document: QueryDocumentSnapshot, completion: @escaping (_ snap: DocumentSnapshot) -> Void) {
        let refarence: DocumentReference = document.data()["item"] as! DocumentReference

        refarence.getDocument { (snap, err) in
            completion(snap!)
        }
    }
}
```

### Postscript

When I went to the detail screen with Modal and returned to the list screen, I could not fetch.

what should I do?

```
Button(action: {
    self.modalPresented.toggle()
}) {
    Text("Go to Detail")

}
.sheet(isPresented: self.$modalPresented) {
    DetailView(onDismiss: {
        self.modalPresented = false
        self.fetcher.fetchData()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean re-fetch, here is possible approach

1. Make your fetch function available for others

```
    class DataFetcher: ObservableObject {
        ...
        func fetchData() { // << here !
           ...
```

2. Initiate re-fetch when details disappear

   ```
       NavigationLink(
           destination: DetailView(itemModel: item)
                            .onDisappear {
                                self.fetcher.fetchData() // << here !
                            }
       ) {
           ItemRow(itemModel: item)
           .frame(width: width, height: height)
       }
   ```